# Batch Show a text or a line under a set

Tags: text, input, batch-file, set, visible

This is something that i searched for very long and never even found another that asked the same !
Is it possible to have a variable input with text under it !
Because, in the code, the text beneath is shown only on ending of the input.
Basicly, i'd like to make a thing like this :

`######################`

`INPUT (the set /p cmd)`

`######################`

The thing i want is to make the line under the set command visible

Comment: So you want the line below the set prompt to be displayed at the same time the user is prompted?

Comment: yes, i'd like to make these nice inputs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No!

It's not possible with pure batch.

There is a simple reason,
as there is no way to go up with the cursor, it's only possible to go back in the same line (with the `CR` or `BACKSPACE` characters).

Only `CLS` can bring the cursor up, but then the screen is empty again.

I know two commands with the possibility to go lines up, but I don't know a way to use them from a batch file.
`set` and `cmd` in a double threaded command window.

```
@echo off
if "%~1"=="intern" (
    prompt %2$G
    call %2
    exit
)
start /b "" "%~f0" intern :thread2

:thread1
prompt :thread1$G
call :cls
echo Use ESC to go up lines
for /L %%n in (1 1 10) DO (
  ping localhost -n 2 > nul
  echo( %%n
)
exit /b

:thread2
set /p var=Press ESC ... NOW!
exit /b
```

But there exists many external tools to set the cursor position ([CursorPos.exe from Aacini](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=17216))